# ui routing not work properly on server

Tags: angularjs

when we click on module section then ui-router URL change but template not load at the current time. after few minutes after template load.
ui-router work properly on localhost but when we deploy on ec2 server then face this problem.

We have state is:

```
.state("Modules", {
    url: "/admin/Modules",
    templateUrl: "angular/templates/modules.html",
    controller: "ModuleController",
    resolve: {
        $title: function () {
            return 'Modules';
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You're missing a 'name' in the state, I believe.

Comment: on local host it is working properly. no state missing, but when we deploy on server then ui router url change but templateurl load take some time.